# Embedding PHPRunner code on a website

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database project using PHPRunner to show data from a MySQL table in GridView. This project is saved in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\output'. When we run PHPRunner, this project runs on a XAMPP server in preview mode, but when we close the PHPRunner application, the project stops running in the XAMPP server.

How can we use this project code on my another website, so that the project can stay running? How would we use/embed this project into the site?

Answer (score 1):

`PHPrunner` uses inbuilt server to preview your generated application. So quite obvious when you close Runner it will close the inbuilt server connection as well. You will have to move the `output` folder to `root folder` of your web server. If you look inside your project folder, you will find a folder named `output`, move this folder to the `root folder` of your web server, it should work fine.

Make sure your web server is powered to use PHP and other drivers related to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you have
C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\output

Then, copy the C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1**output** output folder to httdocs so it's like C:\xampp\htdocs\output it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url: it should be something like: http://localhost/project1/output.  This when u run it with xamp. But when u open phptunner then it's server run it with different address